# AWS sdk: how to slow down requests

Tags: php, aws-sdk

**The scenario:**

I use this function to upload a entire directory to AWS bucket at once and some folders are really big (like 30GBs) of photos.

```
$client->uploadDirectory(
  MY_SOURCE,
  SPACES_NAME,
  DESTINATION,
  array(
    'concurrency' => 1,
    'debug'          => TRUE,
    'force'            => FALSE,
    'options'        => array(
      'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
    ),
  )
);
```

**The error:**
Even with concurrency = 1, after a while my script end's up with the following error:

> 503 Slowdown Please reduce your request rate.

**My question is**

Is there some parameter that limit requests? Readding docs I can't find a way to make this function slow down requests. I know there's a limit of 100 files/second and I want to obey this limit, but don't know where to put this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Middlewares to slow down the requests. Something like this:

```
use Aws\Middleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

...

$s3Client->getHandlerList()->appendInit(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
    sleep(1);
    return $request;
}));

$s3Client->uploadDirectory(...);
```

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/handlers-and-middleware.html).

Comment: Nice, but sadly I'm not using Laravel, just pure PHP but I'v found a way and will post soon as possible.

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel It is not a  Laravel, it is AWS PHP SDK, look at the link I posted.

Comment: Can you post full code (with my code inside of it) ? I'm struggling  but with no success.

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel I just did, see if it works for you

Comment: Thank you, just let me check one thing: if one directory has 33gb photos, it will try to upload all photos and after that sleep for 1 sec?

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel it will sleep every request, I think

Comment: Yeah so that's the problem. I'm making a single request. I'v found another way, just waiting a few minutes to see if worked, but thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'v found a solution:

**First**, I have a specific server to do this, scripts run without time limit and can use a really good ammount of memory.

```
   $counter     = 0;
$files      = scanDirAndSubdir($folder);
foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_file($file)){

        $ACL = 'private';

        $insert[]       = $client->getCommand('putObject',array(
            'Bucket'        => SPACES_NAME,
            'Key'           => $file,
            'SourceFile'    => $file,
            'ACL'           => $ACL,

        ));

        if($counter==100){
            // Executes all commands at once
            $pool = new Aws\CommandPool($client, $insert);
            $promisse = $pool->promise();
            $promisse->wait();

            $counter = 0;
            sleep(1);
        }
        $counter ++;
    }
}
```